# building a subtheme using stark as the base theme but getting this error in the info.yml

Tags: theming

i keep getting this error. The error goes away when i remove the info.yml file from the subtheme. I upload the subtheme in the root theme directory. I've added the error message along with the info.yml file, libraries.yml file, and the .theme file below.

> Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Missing required keys (name) in themes/jetsetterguide/Jetsetterguide.info.yml in Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserDynamic->parse() (line 57 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoParserDynamic.php).
> Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParser->parse() (Line: 554)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->createExtensionInfo() (Line: 266)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeExtensionList->createExtensionInfo() (Line: 316)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->doList() (Line: 113)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeExtensionList->doList() (Line: 282)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getList() (Line: 72)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeHandler->listInfo() (Line: 55)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeAccessCheck->checkAccess() (Line: 69)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeNegotiator->determineActiveTheme() (Line: 405)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->initTheme() (Line: 96)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->getActiveTheme() (Line: 75)
> Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo() (Line: 816)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm() (Line: 284)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 580)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 169)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 81)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 718)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

***Here is the info.yml file I've added:***

Comment: Please delimit the code blocks. They are illegible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the details.

1. Theme machine names (name of files) need to be all lowercase.
2. Your .theme file is missing an opening `<?php` tag.
3. `Global-styling:` needs to be lowercase as well, and the line break removed.
4. In the info file everything below `regions:` needs to be indented.
5. In the info file everything below `libraries:` needs to be indented and prefixed with a `-` .

Comment: i have corrected all but now getting this error: Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Missing required keys (name) in themes/jetsetterguide/Jetsetterguide.info.yml in Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserDynamic->parse() (line 57 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoParserDynamic.php).

Comment: im fairly new to drupal.

Comment: is it saying the name key missing. if thats causing the error. the name key for the subtheme is there.

Comment: @beauthis6 – `Jetsetterguide.info.yml` still is uppercase. Fix it. In all file names. That's the first 1.) point in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply @leymannx still getting the same error code: Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Missing required keys (name) in themes/jetsetterguide/jetsetterguide.info.yml in Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserDynamic->parse() (line 57 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoParserDynamic.php).